# Repeating PHP Queries with New Select Values?

Tags: php, loops, pdo, prepared-statement

Is there an easier way to do this instead of writing the same line of code 100+ times? I need the value of the field L_key each time as you will notice:

```
$query1 = "SELECT L_key FROM profiles WHERE v_key = '$L1_key'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbh, $query1);
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $L2_key = $row['L_Key'];
    $query2 = "UPDATE profiles SET min = min + 1 WHERE v_key = '$L2_key'";
    mysqli_query($dbh, $query2);
} 

$query3 = "SELECT L_key FROM profiles WHERE v_key = '$L2_key'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbh, $query1);
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $L3_key = $row['L_Key'];
    $query2 = "UPDATE profiles SET min = min + 1 WHERE v_key = '$L3_key'";
    mysqli_query($dbh, $query2);
} 

$query3 = "SELECT L_key FROM profiles WHERE v_key = '$L3_key'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbh, $query1);
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $L4_key = $row['L_Key'];
    $query2 = "UPDATE profiles SET min = min + 1 WHERE v_key = '$L4_key'";
    mysqli_query($dbh, $query2);
} 

$query3 = "SELECT L_key FROM profiles WHERE v_key = '$L4_key'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbh, $query1);
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $L5_key = $row['L_Key'];
    $query2 = "UPDATE profiles SET min = min + 1 WHERE v_key = '$L5_key'";
    mysqli_query($dbh, $query2);
}
```

Do I use a loop? If so, can you please show me a code to execute this over and over as I am still learning and do not know what a loop is? Or, is there a different method?

Comment: This is an ideal use case for PDO and parameterized queries.

Comment: Hint: Every time you repeat yourself in code *even once*, you're Doing It Wrong. ;-)

Comment: @Tomalak: Yes, that is why I figured there was a better method!

Comment: @Jessica: What exactly are you trying to do with your selects/updates? Where does `$L1_key` come from and when does the whole thing stop?

Comment: @Tomalak It's kind of like a tree where v_key is a child and L_key is a parent. I am trying to add 1 to min for each parent in line all the way up to the very first parent/ancestor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a recursive structure in your profiles table (`v_key => (l_key : v_key)=> ( l_key... )`) and SQL does not really handle recusion terribly well with simple queries. Your options are to write a stored procedure or handle this with PHP. Since your a beginner, I'd imagine that PHP is far simpler for this task:

```
<?php
// define a variable on the outside -- we'll need it for each iteration
$lKey;
// If you know how many are going to be used, use a for loop because 
// then you know you won't get some sort of nasty infinite recursion issue.
// $count is however many times this needs to operate.
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ )
// while( true ) // <-- this will keep going until "break" is called.
// If you don't know how many will be used. Comment out the for loop
// and uncomment thie while loop.
{
    // your initial query -- I added a limit because you only need one
    // and there is no sense in doing anything more than what you need
    $query1 = "SELECT L_key FROM profiles WHERE v_key = '$lKey' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbh, $query1);
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) // so far so good. 
    {
        $lKey = $row['L_Key']; // assign that outside variable to the new key
        // and run the necessary update.
        $query2 = "UPDATE profiles SET min = min + 1 WHERE v_key = '$lKey'";
        mysqli_query($dbh, $query2);
    } 
    else
    {
        break;
    }
    // as of right now, $lKey is now the value from the select above.
    // which means that you'll be able to start the next loop with it.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use the mysql_num_rows OR mysql_result to get the total numbers, so you can use a while:

```
<? $a = 0; while($total != $a) { //query $a++; } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pdo and solve all your worries. This is cinche in pdo using prepared statements. Will even perform better.

Comment: No clue what PDO is. Trying to find a tutorial..Could you give me an example script that I could work with?